# Can we use glue function inside a knitr kable function?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, r-glue

I have multiple table sets (table set 1, table set 2,...) so I want to create a function that would:

1. knit my table (in R markdown)
2. and automatically change the table caption depending on the table set I'm using

Below is the function I create, however when I run the function it returns me:

1. a table (which I expect)
2. a line `[1] "1"` (I don't know what this is and why the function returns this)
   Can you please help me explain that line and how to remove it?

You can reproduce using the codes below

```
table.set1 <- rbind(c(3, 27),
                    c(33, 9))
rownames(table.set1) <- c("Studying", "Not-studying")
colnames(table.set1) <- c("Men", "Women")

myfunction <- function(mydata, mytext) {
            knitr::kable(mydata,
                        caption = glue::glue("Table set {print(mytext)}")
            )
}


> myfunction(mydata = table.set1, mytext = "1")
## [1] "1"
##
##
## Table set 1
##
## |             | Men| Women|
## |:------------|---:|-----:|
## |Studying     |   3|    27|
## |Not-studying |  33|     9|

> class(myfunction(mydata = table.set1, mytext = "1"))
## [1] "1"
## [1] "knitr_kable"
```

Comment: why do you need the `print()`?

Comment: @Mike Oh silly me... I've removed the print() and now it works like a charm. Thank you so much!!